# ASP .NET Update command different SQL Data Sources

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource, detailsview

I have DetailsView that automatically selects data from a datasource. Within that detailsview I have 2 dropdown lists bound from a different datasource. On update I want the text and value of each drop down list to store into the database.

I can't seem to get the value of the dropdown lists so I can update the paramaters before the SQL command is executed. Or if there is another way to do so that'd be great.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="UserProfile" runat="server"
     AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="UserId" DefaultMode="Edit"
     DataSourceID="UserProfileDataSource" onitemupdated="UserProfile_ItemUpdated" OnPageIndexChanging="UserProfile_PageIndexChanging">
     <Fields>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="fname" HeaderText="First Name:"
               SortExpression="fname" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="lname" HeaderText="Last Name:"
               SortExpression="lname" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="Address:"
               SortExpression="address" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="City:"
               SortExpression="city" />
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State:" SortExpression="state">
              <EditItemTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="State_en" DataValueField="StateId">
                  </asp:DropDownList>
              </EditItemTemplate>
              <InsertItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("state") %>'></asp:TextBox>
              </InsertItemTemplate>
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("state") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="zip" HeaderText="Zip Code:"
               SortExpression="zip" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="phoneNum" HeaderText="Phone Number:"
               SortExpression="phoneNum" />
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Auto Carrier:" SortExpression="autoCarrier">
              <EditItemTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="CarrerID">
                  </asp:DropDownList>
              </EditItemTemplate>
              <InsertItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("autoCarrier") %>'></asp:TextBox>
              </InsertItemTemplate>
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("autoCarrier") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="policyNum" HeaderText="Policy Number:"
               SortExpression="policyNum" />
                     <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
     </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="UserProfileDataSource" runat="server"
          ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>"
          SelectCommand="SELECT [fname], [lname], [address], [city], [state], [zip], [phoneNum], [autoCarrier], [policyNum], [accountid] ,[UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId)" 
    OnSelecting="UserProfileDataSource_Selecting" 
    OnUpdating="OnSqlUpdating" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE UserProfile SET
    stateId = @stateId,
    carrierId = @carrierId,
    fname = @fname,
    lname= @lname,
    address = @address,
    city = @city,
    state = @state,
    zip = @zip,
    phoneNum = @phoneNum,
    autoCarrier = @autoCarrier,
    policyNum = @policyNum
    WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId)">
     <SelectParameters>
          <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="Object" />
     </SelectParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="fname" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="lname" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="address" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="city" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="state" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="zip" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="phoneNum" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="autoCarrier" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="policyNum" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="stateId" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="carrierId" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" />
     </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [StateId], [State_en] FROM [States]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [CarrerID], [Name] FROM ### WHERE ([AccountID] = (SELECT [accountid] FROM ### WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId)))" OnSelecting="UserProfileDataSource_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
          <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="Object" />
     </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here's the code Behind that I wrote, but doesn't work:

```
protected void OnSqlUpdating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{

    string state = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    string autoCarrier = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;
    string stateId = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
    string carrierId = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;

    e.Command.Parameters["@state"].Value = state;
    e.Command.Parameters["@autoCarrier"].Value = autoCarrier;
    e.Command.Parameters["@stateId"].Value = stateId;
    e.Command.Parameters["@carrierId"].Value = carrierId;
}
```

I keep getting:

Error   99  The name 'DropDownList1' does not exist in the current context
Error   102 The name 'DropDownList1' does not exist in the current context
Error   101 The name 'DropDownList2' does not exist in the current context
Error   103 The name 'DropDownList2' does not exist in the current context

I'm new to ASP so any suggestions you recommend or cleaning up of bad code practices is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not access `DropDownList1` and `DropDownList2` directly because there are `TemplateField`  for the  `DetailsView` control. After data binding you can use :

```
DropDownList1 myDropDownList =(DropDownList)UserProfile..Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("DropDownList1");
string state = myDropDownList .SelectedItem.Text;
```

for passing the parameter you need to use OnUpdating Event.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="UserProfileDataSource" runat="server"  

OnUpdating="UserProfileDataSource_Updating"

          ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
          SelectCommand="SELECT [fname], [lname], [address], [city], [state], [zip], [phoneNum], [autoCarrier], [policyNum], [accountid] ,[UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId)" 
    OnSelecting="UserProfileDataSource_Selecting" 
    OnUpdating="OnSqlUpdating" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE UserProfile SET
    stateId = @stateId,
    carrierId = @carrierId,
    fname = @fname,
    lname= @lname,
    address = @address,
    city = @city,
    state = @state,
    zip = @zip,
    phoneNum = @phoneNum,
    autoCarrier = @autoCarrier,
    policyNum = @policyNum
    WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId)">
     <SelectParameters>
          <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="Object" />
     </SelectParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="fname" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="lname" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="address" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="city" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="state" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="zip" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="phoneNum" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="autoCarrier" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="policyNum" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="stateId" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="carrierId" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" />
     </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [StateId], [State_en] FROM [States]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [CarrerID], [Name] FROM ### WHERE ([AccountID] = (SELECT [accountid] FROM ### WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId)))" OnSelecting="UserProfileDataSource_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
          <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="Object" />
     </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

then in the code behind

```
  protected void UserProfileDataSource_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                e.Command.Parameters["@ParamaterName"].Value = // The Value you get from the drop         downlist
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. I'll give this a try tomorrow. To be clear though, I already had an onUpdating call. I can just use that, correct? Also any insight on how to assign values to the drop down list on Page Load?

Comment: do you mean you want to add items to the drop down list on page load ?

Comment: No, I want to set the item the user selected onUpdating as the default value displayed. Currently the first item in the list is always displayed.

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I got it figured out. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: good luck man, sorry i was not able to reply to ur last comment in a fast way. I think because of time difference since I am in Dubai.